# Click on Link in robotium

Tags: robotium

How can I make Robotium click on a particular link in a page?

Comment: We don't know what you're talking about. Can you edit your question to include more details about what exactly you're trying to do? What is robotium?

Comment: [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) is a Selenium-like testing framework for Android.

Answer (score 7):

You should try clicking the the anchor text in the link.
For example, if the link says www.google.com you can do this:

```
this.solo.clickOnText("www.google.com");
```

It is working for me. It should work for you too.

Answer (score 3):

You will get solution by using

> solo.clickOnText(url);

Answer (score 2):

I recommended you to install TestDroid eclipse plugin, it seems like Selenium IDE but for Robotium, obviously

Answer (score 2):

You can use solo.clickOnText() as you purpose is only to click on the link which will be solved by this.

I have fixed so many issues of mine by solo.clickOnText()

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In robotium we have the below function to click on the particular text
solo.clickOnText(String str);

example:
String str="www.google.com";
solo.clickOnText(str);

Answer (score 1):

You can use clickOnHtmlElement method provided by Testdroid in library, which extends robotium-solo.

http://docs.testdroid.com/_pages/extsolo.html